# Stop Firefox from scrolling to first search result when using CTRL-F

Tags: firefox

I use CTRL-F to find things in a page of Firefox often. But its annoying how it always scrolls my page to the first search result. I don't want it to scroll at all, just highlight the search results. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an extension to change this behavior of Firefox.

Below are some extensions that sound promising (I haven't tested any).

- [Multiple Search and Highlight](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multiple-highlight/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search)
- [Search Highlighter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/search-highlighter-2/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search)
- [Search and Highlight](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/search-and-highlight/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search)
- [Highlight](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/highlight-by-trix/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search)
- [Multi-Keywords Highlighter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-keywords-highlighter/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search).